# How to manage my shared dependencies between different modules?

Tags: java, guice

I have the following services

`TopService that injects 
    MidService that injects
        LowService`

I want to use `TopService` with `LowServiceA` in one maven project (let's call it ProjectA). ProjectB depends on another maven project (call ProjectB) that uses the `TopService` with `LowServiceB`.

Below is how I have ProjectA's Guice Module defined:

```
ProjectAModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new PrivateModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(TopService.class);
            bind(MidService.class);
            bind(LowService.class).toInstance(new LowServiceA());
        });
        install(new PrivateModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            install(new ProjectBModule());
            bind(TopService.class);
            bind(MidService.class);
            bind(LowService.class).toInstance(new LowServiceB());
        });
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering if this is the best way to configre my dependencies. One thing I don't like about this approach is that I have to manually bind `TopService`, `MidService`, and `LowService` each time.

Answer (score 0):

just make CommonsModule and ProjectAModule and ProjectBModule and create injector using 2 modules depending on project.

CommonsModule should contain

```
 bind(TopService.class);
 bind(MidService.class);
```

and ProjectAModule/ProjectBModule

```
bind(LowService.class).toInstance(new LowServiceA());
```

or

```
bind(LowService.class).toInstance(new LowServiceB());
```